# How to find train_losses and val_losses in Tensorflow, Neural machine translation with attention

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am learning Neural machine translation from this tutorial
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention#restore_the_latest_checkpoint_and_test

But seems like there are no `train_losses` and `val_losses` in the tutorial (only `batch_loss`).

Is there any way to get loss value history like what we did with another model

Ex.

```
train_loss = seqModel.history['loss']
val_loss   = seqModel.history['val_loss']
train_acc  = seqModel.history['acc']
val_acc    = seqModel.history['val_acc']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that tutorials, there have actually. When they use

```
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
  start = time.time()

  enc_hidden = encoder.initialize_hidden_state()
  total_loss = 0

  for (batch, (inp, targ)) in enumerate(dataset.take(steps_per_epoch)):
    batch_loss = train_step(inp, targ, enc_hidden)
    total_loss += batch_loss
```

By that, they're computing the training loss that is coming from the `train_step` method. But there is no validation set so no validation loss is shown.

---

Based on your comment, you need to write the `test_step` function and use it in the training loop. Here is a minimum representation to get the validation loss.

```
@tf.function
def test_step(inp, targ, enc_hidden):
    loss = 0 
    enc_output, enc_hidden = encoder(inp, enc_hidden, training=False)
    dec_hidden = enc_hidden
    dec_input = tf.expand_dims([targ_lang.word_index['<start>']] * BATCH_SIZE, 1)

    for t in range(1, targ.shape[1]):
      predictions, dec_hidden, _ = decoder(dec_input, dec_hidden, 
                                           enc_output, training=False)
      loss += loss_function(targ[:, t], predictions)
      dec_input = tf.expand_dims(targ[:, t], 1)
      
    batch_loss = (loss / int(targ.shape[1]))
    return batch_loss
```

To use it in the custom training loop, you would do as follows. Note, I'm using the same `dataset`, but practically we need to create a separate validation dataset.

```
EPOCHS = 5
history = {'loss':[], 'val_loss':[]}

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    start = time.time()
    
    enc_hidden = encoder.initialize_hidden_state()
    total_loss = 0
    for (batch, (inp, targ)) in enumerate(dataset.take(steps_per_epoch)):
        batch_loss = train_step(inp, targ, enc_hidden)
        total_loss += batch_loss
    if (epoch + 1) % 2 == 0:
        checkpoint.save(file_prefix=checkpoint_prefix)
    history['loss'].append(total_loss.numpy()/steps_per_epoch)
    print(f'Epoch {epoch+1} Loss {total_loss/steps_per_epoch:.4f}')

    total_loss = 0
    for (batch, (inp, targ)) in enumerate(dataset.take(steps_per_epoch)):
        batch_loss = test_step(inp, targ, enc_hidden)
        total_loss += batch_loss
    history['val_loss'].append(total_loss.numpy()/steps_per_epoch)
    print(f'Epoch {epoch+1} Val Loss {total_loss/steps_per_epoch:.4f}')
        
    print(f'Time taken for 1 epoch {time.time()-start:.2f} sec\n')
```

Next,

```
history['loss']
history['val_loss']
```

Comment: If you're new in this field, I friendly suggest you start with some simple examples. Because that tutorial uses `custom_trainning_loop`, which I think can be tough for a starter. So, it's better to start with these examples: https://keras.io/examples/nlp/ - mix complexities.

Comment: thanks you so much, for your help, but is there the way to find validation loss in this case?

Comment: Updated, have a look.